# Get-CacheHost shows OK on one server but Unknown on other server

Tags: distributedcache, app-fabric

I have the Distributed Cache service running on three servers in my 2013 farm. I was attempting to take it off of the WFE so it would only run on the two existing Application servers, or what will become the App servers once I am done loaded them with services and Scheduled Jobs. The issue I am encountering however is that when I am on any server other than the App server the Get-CacheHost command returns Service Status of Unknown for the App sever and OK for the other two servers.

I have checked and this result is consistent on both the WFE and the other App server. I have checked all the firewall rules and the AppFabric is approved for Inbound and Outbound communications and I do not see any errors in any of the event logs. The weirdest thing is that the Resource Monitor shows the DistributedCacheService connect to all of the servers in the Farm and they are all using the standard, out of the box port of 22233. I've reset the Cache, I've rebooted the App server, I've added and removed the service from the App server but nothing works, I'm stumped and I am hoping someone can drop some knowledge here.

App Server results:

```
PS C:\Users\sp2013_setup> Get-CacheHost

HostName : CachePort          Service Name            Service Status Version
                                                                     Info
--------------------          ------------            -------------- ----------
SharePoint02.fs.dew.twu:22233 AppFabricCachingService UP             3
                                                                     [3,3][1,3]
SharePoint03.fs.dew.twu:22233 AppFabricCachingService UP             3
                                                                     [3,3][1,3]
shrPt2013.fs.dew.twu:22233    AppFabricCachingService UP             3
                                                                     [3,3][1,3]
```

WFE Results:

```
PS C:\Users\sp2013_setup> Get-CacheHost

HostName : CachePort          Service Name            Service Status Version
                                                                     Info
--------------------          ------------            -------------- ----------
SharePoint02.fs.dew.twu:22233 AppFabricCachingService UP             3
                                                                     [3,3][1,3]
SharePoint03.fs.dew.twu:22233 AppFabricCachingService UNKNOWN        0
                                                                     [0,0][0,0]
shrPt2013.fs.dew.twu:22233    AppFabricCachingService UP             3
                                                                     [3,3][1,3]
```

Anyone have any ideas what might correct this or what step I have missed to fully enable this communication?

Comment: Do you find any errors in your ULS-Logs when executing Get-CacheHost on the WFE-Srever? Please include logs from all servers (use ULS-Viewer from Microsoft and add all Servers with CTRL+R) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020

Comment: No nothing in the logs that I see however I now think its a network issue more than an application issue. I've noticed some oddities on one server so I tried to trace the route to the other severs and it just times out where the App server traces and completes to the WFE. I'll update more once I have the network team do some digging.

Answer (score 1):

On the App server and WFE server run the following command and see if you have the same GUID:

```
Get-Cache | select CacheName
```

Output

```
CacheName
---------
default
DistributedAccessCache_76d4d782-a24d-4621-85fd-cfe822386b57
DistributedActivityFeedCache_76d4d782-a24d-4621-85fd-cfe822386b57
DistributedActivityFeedLMTCache_76d4d782-a24d-4621-85fd-cfe822386b57
DistributedBouncerCache_76d4d782-a24d-4621-85fd-cfe822386b57
DistributedDefaultCache_76d4d782-a24d-4621-85fd-cfe822386b57
DistributedLogonTokenCache_76d4d782-a24d-4621-85fd-cfe822386b57
DistributedSearchCache_76d4d782-a24d-4621-85fd-cfe822386b57
DistributedSecurityTrimmingCache_76d4d782-a24d-4621-85fd-cfe822386b57
DistributedServerToAppServerAccessTokenCache_76d4d782-a24d-4621-85fd-cfe8223...
DistributedViewStateCache_76d4d782-a24d-4621-85fd-cfe822386b57
```

If not, you probably have two different cache clusters, and you need to remove one of them.